# Trying to write results of a set into a csv file in Python but only getting one line to print

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, export-to-csv

Stuck on something and hoping to get some ideas on what I'm doing wrong here.  I have written out a web scraping program that scrapes all web links from the census.gov website but when I try to write my results out to a csv file, I am only getting one of the links to write out instead of the full list.  See code below.  To ensure my set was pulling correctly, I added in a line of code that first printed the results of my set and then goes into writing out the results in csv.  The initial results look correct, as I'm seeing a full list of links.  However, I am not sure why I am only able to write out one row of data to excel csv:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import bs4, csv
search_link = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
search = requests.get(search_link).text
raw_html = search
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
import re
links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': re.compile('uscb*')})
urls_set = set()
for link in links:
    my_links = link.get("href")
    if my_links not in urls_set:
        urls_set.add(my_links)
        print(my_links)
with open("Current Estimate Result.csv",'wb') as f:
         cw = csv.writer(f)
         cw.writerows(my_links)
         print(my_links)        
         f.close()
```

Comment: Add an csv output please

Comment: So I added "cw = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames='',restval='', extrasaction='ignore', dialect='excel')" to the one line but still only seeing the one row of data when I print the value of "my_links"

Comment: I refered to the output you're getting now

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `my_links` variable holds the last read URL. So `cw.writerows(my_links)` writes out just that URL and not all of the URLs - which are actually stored in `urls_set`.

However, I'm not sure your usage of the `writerows()` method is entirely correct. [This method expects an iterator of row objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (typically a list of lists). Each nested list represents a row in the CSV file.

So it may be better to hold the URLs in a list rather than a set, and then wrap each URL in it's own list (row) before adding. For example:

```
urls_list = []
for link in links:
    my_link = [link.get("href")]  # A row in the csv
    if my_link not in urls_list:
        urls_list.append(my_link)

    ...
    cw.writerows(urls_list)  # Pass the overall list
```

Note I renamed `my_links` to `my_link` in the example above. Using a list would also ensure that the order would be preserved.

Comment: This helped.  Thanks a lot